# PHP can't connect to MYSQL after restart - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli

spent a few hours racking my brains, trying to fix this but I fear I'm not getting anywhere.

I set up localhost as a lamp environment yesterday on Ubuntu 15.10, everything was running fine and I made some good progress. Now I restart this morning and my project which I know I left working is now giving me

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/includes/mysql.php on line 6
```

Now I know that there isn't a mistake in the code and mysql and apache is definately running.

```
elliot@elliotsLaptop:~$ mysqladmin -u root -p status
Enter password: 
Uptime: 3588  Threads: 1  Questions: 19  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 69  
Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 62  Queries per second avg: 0.005.

elliot@elliotsLaptop:~$ service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-04-20 09:02:18 BST; 1h 1min ago
```

Also I made no changed to the PHP.ini file when I originally set it up, but now both mysqli_connect and mysql_connect are both undefined functions and mysqli is an undefined class.

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/includes/mysql.php on line 6
```

So it seems to be some kind of setting has change inside my php setup but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

This is PHP Version 5.6.11. Anyone have any experience with this kind of problem? I'm close to reinstalling PHP but I'd rather understand what is going on or what I may be doing wrong.

Any advice would be severly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your `mysqli` module isn't loaded.

Comment: Check if the module is loaded `php -m | grep mysqli`, if the line `mysqli` shows, its loaded, if not .. well ;)

Comment: Open terminal and check this  `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and you will also need to install the php module for mysql `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Comment: Hey, php -m | grep mysqli is returning nothing for me at this point, however I can still log into and run MYSQL fine from the command line using mysql -u root -p. So do I need to install mysql server and php5-mysql, surely if the connection was working yesterday it was already installed? Also both mysqli and mysql_connect are undefined functions so is it definitely the mysqli module?

Also thanks for the help!

Comment: @ElliotHolman K, then locate your `php.ini` with `php --ini` and check the line where it says `Loaded Configuration File:`. Get the files location and check if the mysqli extension is loaded (not commented with # or ;), e.g. `grep -n "extension" /path/to/php.ini`

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm not that familiar with what an .ini file should look like but the only commented out sections in the ini file that relate to mysql or mysqli are ;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On >>>> ;mysqlnd.net_read_buffer_size = 32768 >>> ;mysqlnd.net_cmd_buffer_size = 2048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, taking the mysql connection out of an include and putting it directly onto the page that was using it seems to have fixed the problem. I have no real idea why this would be the case but everything now seems to be working as expected.

Thanks a lot to everyone who tried to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Command:

Latest phpMyAdmin versions require mysqli extension and will no longer work with mysql.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Please add below line php.ini

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

Please restart server hope this works

Comment: OP said nothing about phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Hi Ankit, I made these changes and while php5-mysql did need installing it doesn't seem to have changed anything. Thanks for the idea though.